# Anti virus for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, antivirus

We are running Symantec anti virus on Ubuntu 16.04,
but now we've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and Symantec doesn't support Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there any anti virus for Ubuntu 18.04 out there which can match Symantec-like anti virus support?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ClamAV and its GUI front end ClamTK works for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Link [here.](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-clamav-linux-antivirus-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktp/)

You can download ClamTK from the Ubuntu Software Center.